# How to Nested Classes in Python when trying to write a __call__ overwrite

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, class, object

So hopefully below illustrates my point. I want to set the translate attributes once and then be able to pass any mods (like translate) into the modLevels function. The only way I know how to do this is through nested classes, but I can't figure out how to get access to the outer class points. Any ideas or maybe even let me know if I'm going about this all wrong. THANKS!

```
class PointSet:
  def __init__(self, points):
     self.points = points

  class translate:
     def __init__(self, xmove=0, ymove=0):
        self.xmove = xmove
        self.ymove = ymove
     def __call__(self):
        for p in Outer.points: # <-- this part isnt working
           p.x += self.xmove; p.y += self.ymove

def modLevels(levels, *mods):
  for lev in range(levels):
     for mod in mods:
        mod

set1 = PointSet(...list of point objects here...)
coolMod = translate(xmove=5)
change(5, coolMod)
```

Comment: It's not clear why you need the nested class and why you're referring to something called `Outer` which is never defined.

Comment: In order to pass any member function to modLevels and be able to call in in modLevels without having to call it with different arguments every time, the translate has to be initialized with some values originally. That's why the two nested classes. and the Outer is trying to refer to the outer class which I don't know what the best way to do so is

Comment: What you are designing is a kind of composition or aggregation between the class `PointSet` and `translate`. It looks like a misconception. `translate` should be a method, not a class. Again, what do you want to translate `PointSet` or `Point`? I think you ought to define a `Point` class with a `translate` method.

Comment: Ok you should describe your intended design in your question, without the nested classes so the problem you're trying to solve is clear. Then maybe describe how the nested classes make whatever you're trying to do better. As it is, you have a snippet of code from which you think others can derive your ideas but that's not really the case.

Answer (score 2):

Pass it as a parameter.

```
class PointSet:
    def __init__(self, points):
        self.points = points

    class translate:
        def __init__(self, xmove=0, ymove=0, parent):
            self.parent = parent
            self.xmove = xmove
            self.ymove = ymove
    def __call__(self):
        for p in self.parent.points:
            p.x += self.xmove; p.y += self.ymove
```

Self-contained example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = [1,2,3]
    class B:
        def __init__(self, parent):
            self.data = [4,5,6]
            self.parent = parent
        def access(self):
            print(self.parent.data)

a = A()
b = a.B(a)
b.access()
```

However, as explained in comments, you don't need a nested class at all.

```
class PointSet:
    def __init__(self, points):
        self.points = points

    def translate(self, x, y):
        for p in self.points:
            p.x += x
            p.y += y
```

Comment: Ok that answer its question but this is clearly a misconception. This solution is not very useful for beginners. (He can do it's homework himself) right?

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE - I was originally going to comment that I've never seen a necessary nested class, but what I have seen (in my own code, no less) is things being declared in an inappropriate scope due to an incomplete understanding of how to pass objects around, so I figured I'd demonstrate that instead.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE - This answer didn't feel complete without any example of how to do this without a nested class, so I've added that.

Comment: I agree. Nested classes could be useful when you have inheritance: the child class inherits and overrides the nested class. Classic use case: composition.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help. I found a way to access the outer class on ubuntu forums. [Solved referencing outer class from an inner class](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1900527).
I needed to do this to pass a few parameters to the translation  constructor and then overwrite the call function to use those parameters. This is a similar concept to a C++ function object like what you would pass to an STL algorithm: [more on function objects](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/functors-function-objects-in-c++.html).